# Using var in JavaScript with a for loop issue?

Tags: javascript

I know I can use the let keyword here to get the desired outcome, but I would like to know why clicking on the div items alerts #5 for each div.

```js
var div;
var box = document.getElementById('box');
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.onClick = function() {
    alert('this is box # ' + i);
  }
  box.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29558498/9513184

Comment: Because by the time you click on the div, the loop has completed and i has a value of 5.

Comment: Because you are creating click function with referenced i not current value of i. Then whatever you click, reference same i which is 4.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the anonymous function to the click, it does not run its body. Its body of codes runs only when it is clicked so the first time i variable is used in the function it has already the value of 4. You need to evaluate current value of i while it is in the loop and place it in the function generated, by a function generating function. Otherwise it will take a reference to i and use its latest value always.